# Printing in Base 10-16 with letters

Tags: c++

I am stuck on a project where I have to print out any number in any base from 10-16. The problem is that in those bases, you have to add a letter to the front, which I don't really understand how to do with recursion. Can anyone help me?

```
int conversionFunction(int num, int base)
{
     if (num == 0)
        return 0;
     int x = num % base;
     num /= base;
     if (x < 0)
        num = num + 1; 
     conversionFunction(num, base);
     if (x < 0){
        cout << x+(base * -1);
     }
     else{
        cout << x;
        return x;
     }
}
```

If I do 246 in base 16, I get 156. I know that the actual answer should be F6. 15 translates to F when converting. But how would I do that?

Comment: Something like `'A' + (15 - 10)`?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be stuck just on the problem of converting between bases. I can think of two ways to do it:

1. Divide by decreasing powers of the radix, from n-1 to 0, where n is the largest power. That requires you to know the largest value that you might have to convert. Each division gives you a digit in the place that corresponds to that power. Using your example, you could decide to go up to four digits, so you'd have:

   246 / 16^^3 = 0
   246 / 16^^2 = 0
   246 / 16^^1 = F
     6 / 16^^0 = 6

So the answer is 0x00F6.

2. Use modulo arithmetic with increasing powers of the radix, from 1 to n. Again, each operation gives you a digit in the place that corresponds to the power of the radix. Using the same example:

   246 mod 16^^1 = 6
   240 mod 16^^2 = F

So again, you've got 0xF6.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
static const char* digits = "0123456789abcdef";
```

and

```
cout << digits[num % base];
```

is a nice way. `static` just means that `digits` is has global lifetime but is scoped to your function (basically, you won't have to recreate it over and over every time you enter your function).

Comment: Where would i put it in the function? I've tried at the end but it doesn't really work, it gives me "0f" for 246 base 10 to base 16 instead of F6

Comment: @Encepti0N You should perform the conversion by hand to understand how to write your algorithm. For a start, if `num == 0` you still have to print `0`. `num % base` is the digit you want to print for a given iteration, and `num / base` is what you should pass to the next recursion step. Since you need to print `num_initial % base` last, make sure you print after the recursive call. That way the numbers you print will be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with comments in the code using a similar approach as in okovkos answer and Calebs second solution. It starts with the least significant digit and extracts until `num` is zero. It supports conversions in the range `(INTMAX_MIN, INTMAX_MAX]` using a base in the range `[2, 36]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint> // std::intmax_t, std::uintmax_t

std::string itos(
    std::intmax_t num,               // number to convert, range: (INTMAX_MIN, INTMAX_MAX]
    const int base=10,               // base, range: [2, 36]
    const std::string& prefix="",    // user defined prefix
    bool add_plus=false)             // add plus sign for positive numbers
{
    static const std::string digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if(base>36 || base<2) return ""; // erroneous base

    std::string rv; // the return value we'll create

    if(num) {
        bool negative = false;
        if(num<0) {
            if(num==INTMAX_MIN) return ""; // the ONE std::intmax_t number you can't use    
            // make it positive for the calculation
            num = -num;
            negative = true;
        }

        std::uintmax_t x;

        while(num) {
            x = num % base; // extract least significant digits index
            rv.insert(rv.begin(), digits[x]); // insert digit first
            num -= x;       // reduce num with the extracted value
            num /= base;    // divide num down for next extraction
        }

        // the below two inserts could be moved to just before the
        // return if you want to add the prefix for the value zero too

        // insert prefix
        rv.insert(0, prefix);

        // insert minus sign if negative or plus if desired
        if(negative) rv.insert(rv.begin(), '-');
        else if(add_plus) rv.insert(rv.begin(), '+');
    } else rv = "0"; // special case

    return rv;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "bin " << itos(255, 2, "0b") << "\n";
    std::cout << "oct " << itos(255, 8, "0") << "\n";
    std::cout << "dec " << itos(255, 10, "", true) << "\n";
    std::cout << "hex " << itos(-INTMAX_MAX, 16, "0x") << "\n";
    std::cout << "hex " << itos(INTMAX_MAX, 16, "0x") << "\n";
}
```

Possible output:

```
bin 0b11111111
oct 0377
dec +255
hex -0x7fffffffffffffff
hex 0x7fffffffffffffff
```